# Is there a way to adjust timing for Chartboost ads to pop up?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, timer, iad, chartboost

I'd like some help knowing if there's a way to change the timing for Chartboost ads to pop up. I like having my ads but showing after every death in my game seems annoying. However, I think they are important to have so I want to be able to play a couple rounds and then it pops up, a few more rounds and then it'll show again..

I have tried adding after this line to make the Chartboost active but it doesn't change.

Thanks for the help

```
[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationGameScreen];
```